# At mysqli 8.0.5 configuration while appliying configuration error: writing configuration | Invalid template

Tags: mysql

MySQL Server 8.0.5 installation fails at “Writing configuration file”
Invalid template

tried reconfiguration several times

### C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Installer for Windows\Logs files says:-

```
An error occurred running netsh.exe delete:
```

The netsh.exe process did not return any error. Review the application log to see if there is a trace of the error.
mysql-installer Information: 10 : The attempt to delete a Windows Firewall rule failed.
You can add or delete a Windows Firewall rule manually by following the instructions at this URL:
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Allow-a-program-to-communicate-through-Windows-Firewall
mysql-installer Information: 10 : Beginning RemoveCompletePage.
mysql-installer Information: 10 : Installer exit

Comment: It's not clear from your question why it was tagged as "SQL-Server". Could you please elaborate?

Comment: I've removed the SQL Server tag (and the error tag, which according to the tag is for syntax errors which this is not) as this is clearly for MySQL. Please don't just add tags, read what they mean and use only the ones relevant to your question. Adding irrelevant tags means your question is going to receive less answers/views, as people won't want to read a question which is unclear. Also, are you really still using Windows Vista? If so, maybe your problem is you're using an out of date OS.

Comment: sorry ... I am using win7 and the problem is solved after I cleared mysql files and used an older installer.